# Webpack build file size grow algebraicly

Tags: javascript, build, webpack, webpack-2

I started using Webpack 2 recently and everytime I build a project (or edit something in --watch mode) - build file growth algebraicly (for example, file is 80kb after first build and it'll become 160kb after re-build and 240 after the third one, so I guess it just appends new file to the end of the old one?)

I keep getting huge build files after just a few minutes of work!

Is there anything I can do?

My config:

```
const PATH = require('path'),
    WEBPACK = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './public/static/health/js/main.js',
        vendor: ['moment', 'underscore']
    },
    output: {
        path: PATH.resolve(__dirname, './public/static/health/js/build/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new WEBPACK.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new WEBPACK.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "vendor.bundle.js"})
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: try     watchOptions: {  poll: true  } or enabling the watch thru devServer

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora watch mode DOES work for me, that's not the problem. It's just the file grows really-really fast

Comment: try using `clean-webpack-plugin`